# Get categories based on time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am making website that have foods and different categories like breakfast,lunch,dinner etc.What I want to do is when user enter to website it will automatically shown that category according to current time.
My **category** table has fields:

- ID
- Name
- Start_time
- End_time

My **Controller** is:

```
public function index()
{
    $now = Carbon::now();
    $Category=DB::table('Categories')
        ->where('Start_time', '>', $now)
        ->where('End_time', '<', $now)
        ->get();

    return view('welcome', compact('Category'));
}

public function categ($Category_id)
{
   $category = Categories::with('food')->findOrFail($Category_id);
   return view('category', compact('category'));
}
```

**Routes** are:

```
Route::get('/','DetailsController@index');
Route::get('category/{Category_id}', 'DetailsController@categ');
```

In my **view**

```
 @foreach ($Category as $categories) 
 <div class="food-box">
 <button 
 style="font-size:14px; width: 230px; height: 30px; background-color: #00A30C; color:white; font-style: italic; text-align: center; font-size: 15px; margin: 0 auto;">

{{$categories->CategoryName}} </button>

 </div>
 @endforeach
```

I am using Carbon api to get current time by using this.

```
<?php 
 $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
 echo $mytime->format('l jS \\of F Y, h:i:s A');
?>
```

I want it shows me category based on current time.if time interval not meet then default page will be shown.How I can do this in laravel?I am new to laravel and didn't find any solution about this.Thanks

Comment: How is Start_time and End_time stored in your database?  Unix timestamps?  Mysql timestamps or datetimes?  Surely you aren't storing them in that format.

Comment: They are stored as Mysql timestamps.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now()
$foods = DB::table('food_table')
            ->where('Start_time', '<', $now)
            ->where('End_time', '>', $now)
            ->get();
```

That will produce something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `food_table` WHERE `Start_time` < '2016-08-29 08:38:00' and `End_time` < '2016-08-29 08:38:00'
```

Alternatively:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
$foods = DB::table('food_table')
            ->whereRaw($now . ' BETWEEN Start_time AND End_time')
            ->get();
```

**UPDATE**

Oh, hold on, this should be `'Category'`, not `'welcome'`!

```
return view('welcome', $Category); // no compact(), change welcome to Category
```

And you don't need the `compact()` function, just pass the collection into the view by itself, as I did above.  If you're still having trouble, try `php artisan tinker`, and test out your query via command line.

Comment: This results nothing.

Comment: Did you replace `food_table` with your own table name?  And is there actually any data that should show up at this moment?

Comment: yes I updated the table name and I have data in tables.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are using to make this query.

Comment: Take out `compact()`

Comment: from index function?

Comment: Altogether.  That function is emptying your collection, I'll update my answer.